# Issue with starting the REST server in Hyperledger Composer Developer Tutorial

Tags: node.js, rest, npm, hyperledger-composer

When following the developer tutorial here:

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html

everything runs fine until "**Step Five: Generating a REST server**"

I get the following messages:

---

**$ composer-rest-server**

? Enter the name of the business network card to use: **admin@my-test-network**

? Specify if you want namespaces in the generated REST API: **never use namespaces**

? Specify if you want to enable authentication for the REST API using Passport: **No**

? Specify if you want to enable event publication over WebSockets: **Yes**

? Specify if you want to enable TLS security for the REST API: **No**

To restart the REST server using the same options, issue the following command:
   composer-rest-server -c admin@my-test-network -n never -w true

Discovering types from business network definition ...
**Connection fails: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.19.0) is not compatible with client (0.18.2)**
It will be retried for the next request.
Exception: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: **Composer runtime (0.19.0) is not compatible with client (0.18.2)**
Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.19.0) is not compatible with client (0.18.2)
    at _checkRuntimeVersions.then.catch (/home/james/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:780:34)
    at

---

I already had an issue with the previous installation steps which was solved over here [hyperledger composer installation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706309/hyperledger-composer-installation-issue)

but there still seems to be some (client) component which is using 0.18.2 and not 0.19.0.

Can someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following solved the issue:

npm install -g composer-rest-server@0.19.0